# How to get String from the AutocompleteTextview of android studio?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

[Actually i had apply the autocompletetextview of editText but problem is that when i clicked on view button the app get's cracked coz of some error or bugs in if (view == View) control attribute]

```
if (view == View) {
  // Checking for empty roll number
  if (Rollno.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
    showMessage("Error", "Please enter Rollno");
    return;
  }
  Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student WHERE rollno='" + Rollno.getText().toString() + "'", null);
  if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    Name.setText(c.getString(1));
    Marks.setText(c.getString(2));
    Dept.setText(c.getString(3));

  }
  //            Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student WHERE rollno='" + Rollno.getText().toString() + "'", null);
  //            if(c1.moveToFirst()){
  //
  //            }
  else {
    showMessage("Error", "Invalid Rollno");
    clearText();
  }
}
```

[image: especially, the error comes in this portion at c.getString(1) on clicking view button it gives name at c.getString(2) on clicking view button it gives marks but when i added Dept which is id of autocompletetextview of editText the app get's cracked..]

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
  Name.setText(c.getString(1));
  Marks.setText(c.getString(2));
  Dept.setText(c.getString(3));

}
```

> so please try to configure out it i had made the separate c.moveToFirst control attribute for it but it won't work and this if statements doesn't return anythings as i publish the all if statement?????<sup><kbd><sub>your text</sub></kbd></sup> above

Comment: Hi Sachin , could you please elaborate a bit on your query and if possible add the log of the exception

Comment: the problem is that, when i just insert the roll no student name ,marks and Dept should be displayed and i applied the autocompletetextview to the dept id of edittext as shown in image.  because of the autocompletetextview of Dept i would not able to Dept.setText(c.getString(3)); do this and app gets cracked.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add some code or the error in logcat